# Pagination does not work with query_posts()

Tags: categories, pagination, query-posts

I trying to add pagination to my WordPress website, it's working fine in main index page,
I am trying to create different main pages for category 
issue with category pages, when click any link of pagination URL change but content still the same 

index page code

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

   /*  post code goes here */

     endwhile;


    the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
) ); 

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;?>
```

category page code

```
<?php

query_posts('cat=5');
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

   /*  post code goes here */

     endwhile;


    the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
) ); 

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;?>
```

I also try this

```
<ul>
    <?php
    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts( array(
        'offset'         => 1,
        'category'       => 5
    ) );

    if ( $myposts ) {
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
) ); 
    ?>
</ul>
```

but only show post, not the pagination

can someone help with this
thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

`the_posts_pagination` works with the global `$wp_query`, so your second method will not work.

`query_posts` modifies the main query but the arguments passed will overwrite any existing values, so all values needed for pagination are lost when you set `cat=5`. But you can [preserve the existing values](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#preserving-existing-query-parameters) by modifying the global query string.

A more efficient way, however, would be to use the [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action hook, e.g.:

```
function mysite_change_cat($query) {
  //if it is a category archive page and main query
  if ($query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('cat', 5);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'mysite_change_cat');
```

However if you are creating completely different pages for certain categories, then you could simply create template files for each of them [named e.g. category-5.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category).